# Windows Azure asp.net web form + c# + Intranet should login with windows credential + internet should take you to login page.

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms

Currently I am developing a Asp.Net Web Form website for my company. We are planning to host this website on Azure Cloud.

Currently the application I am developing is using the logged in windows account to authenticate and authorize the user using the Active Directory.

What I am looking here is, **to take a user to login page if he is accessing from outside the intranet and log him in directly to the application if he is in Internet (outside world).**

If I am moving this application to Azure Cloud (may be with Azure Active Directory) how can I achieve the above.

It would be great if someone can point me to any blogs or help me with a code snippet on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure Active Directory, on your ASP.Net project right click and select "Configure Azure AD Authentication", to do this you should have valid Azure subscription details when it asks, this step will configure your project with TenatId and Secret which are generated in Azure AD as new AD Application. You can search for this AD application using TenantID in Azure portal and check for further configurations like single sign-on.